# Swift: Filter relevant files / ignore subfolders of app package

Tags: swift, file, copy, directory

I want to copy some files from a folder. So I scan the files in that folder. But I get all the details, like the "contents" folder of an app and all the files below. If I copy an app, all the belonging stuff will be copied too. So I like to get only the root files. Is there an option anywhere?

This is the query code:

```
func getFolderEnumerator(directoryUrl:NSURL) -> NSDirectoryEnumerator?
{
    let fileManger = NSFileManager()
    let keys = [NSURLIsDirectoryKey]

    let handler = {
        (url:NSURL!,error:NSError!) -> Bool in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        if url != nil {
            print(url.absoluteString)
        }
        return true
    }

    let enumerator = fileManger.enumeratorAtURL(
        directoryUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys:
        keys, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(),
              errorHandler:handler)

    return enumerator
}
```

And the next function is:

```
func getFileNames(enumerator:NSDirectoryEnumerator, exts:[String]) -> Array<NSURL>
{
    var files = [NSURL]()

    while let url = enumerator.nextObject() as? NSURL
    {
        var isDirectory = ObjCBool(false)
        let exists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(
            url.path!, isDirectory: &isDirectory)

        if exists == true && isDirectory.boolValue == false {
            files.append(url)

        }
    }
    return files
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  .SkipsPackageDescendants in options for

```
if let enumerator = fileManger.enumeratorAtURL(
        directory, includingPropertiesForKeys: keys, options: options, errorHandler:handler)
```